# Match the text between delimiter pipe and remove it and keep the delimiters intact

Tags: java, regex, string

My issue is I have a String with a delimiter after every four characters. I need to match a specific word to those four characters between the delimiters and remove it.

Eg: String txt = "ABCD|BABA|SSRV|LKGD"

Now check the String for BABA, DGHT, LKGD, ADKC and return the String minus these items

Since we found a match for BABA and LKGD. So the result should be the following

Result: txt = "ABCD|SSRV"

Any efficient way to do it?

Comment: I found this on the web txt.replaceAll("\\s*\\bBABA\\b\\s*", " ");           This works but now my Result is ABCD||SSRV|LKGD how can I get rid of the delimiter after or before the matched word

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
String str = "ABCD|BABA|SSRV|LKGD";
String repl = str.replaceFirst("\\|BABA(?=\\||$)", "");
//=> ABCD|SSRV|LKGD
```

To remove both search strings together:

```
String str = "ABCD|BABA|SSRV|LKGD";
String repl = str.replaceAll("\\|(BABA|LKGD)(?=\\||$)", "");
//=> ABCD|SSRV
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for you answer I have tried both replaceFirst and replace All but it doesn't work. Am still getting the entire String.

Comment: I find this on the web txt.replaceAll("\\s*\\bBABA\\b\\s*", " ");           This works but now my result is

Comment: Result is ABCD||SSRV|LKGD how can I get rid of the delimiter after or before the matched word

Comment: I have provided you code in the answer and the output being generated. If you tell me exactly what your input is what your search string is then I can investigate and suggest.

Answer (score 0):

uses guava, but is quite readable.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.base.Joiner;

public class test {
    public static void main(String... args) {

        String txt = "ABCD|BABA|SSRV|LKGD";
        List<String> toBeRemoved = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "BABA", "DGHT","LKGD", "ADKC" });
        List<String> data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(txt.split("\\|")));
        data.removeAll(toBeRemoved);
        System.out.println(Joiner.on("|").join(data));

    }

}
```